# Sonar vision smiley face on art works

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

Does anyone know what is going on with the smiley faces appearing on sonar vision over certain works of art? I assume it is more than one place but I've only noticed it once so far and that is in a bedroom in the safe house mission very early in the game. I've only been playing an hour or so.

[image: Split shot of sonar vision showing smiley face]

Comment: I asked the official Splintercell twitter account and they didn't have any info on it, it was the first they were aware of it.

Comment: +1 one for your findings! very intersting. Im eager to get the answer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

The smiley face is an Easter Egg, a little joke added in by the developers. Little things like that are a lot more common, but Ubisoft often add in jokes and nods. You can find a list of secret easter eggs in the game [here](http://splintercell.wikia.com/wiki/Splinter_Cell_Secrets#Tom_Clancy.27s_Splinter_Cell:_Blacklist).